# How to define default tags with pulumi aws provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, pulumi

What is the correct way to define default tags so that they are applied to all AWS resources in my stack? I have the following provider config, but none of my resources are actually tagged:

```
config:
  aws:defaultTags:
    tags:
      key1: value1
      key2: value2
  aws:region: us-west-1
```

Versions:

```
@pulumi/pulumi@3.10.1
@pulumi/aws@4.15.0
```

Answer (score 5):

Answering my own question after a few hours of trial and error. Based on the sample config in the question:

- Default tags are applied to new resources
- Default tags are applied to resources that are being updated
- Default tags are NOT automatically applied to all existing resources
- Default tags do NOT show up in any scenario during `pulumi preview --diff`

Answer (score 1):

This policy pack is configurable so that you can enforce arbitrary tags without needing to change the pack’s code, making it reusable. For the CLI scenario, we will create a policy-config.json file that specifies the same three required tags shown above:

```
    {
    "all": "mandatory",
    "check-required-tags": {
        "requiredTags": [
            "user:Project",
            "user:Stack",
            "user:Cost Center"
        ]
    }
}
```

Default tags

```
tags
{[key: string]: string}
```

read more- https://www.pulumi.com/blog/automatically-enforcing-aws-resource-tagging-policies/

Comment: To my understanding, a policy like this can check that tags are being defined while doing the pulumi update, but policies never change any resources. What I am looking for is for a way to add those tags in a centralised way instead of having to define them on each and every resource.

Comment: The link provided in this answer "enforcing aws resource tagging policies" has code examples for auto-tagging resources.